# Which css files to include for tether?

Tags: tether

The tether [docs](https://github.com/HubSpot/tether#install) say no word about how to get it running (only `bower install tether` which downloads it all). For JS it is clear, since there is only one relevant file in the dist folder of the repo.

But which files are needed from https://github.com/HubSpot/tether/tree/master/dist/css? Is `tether.min.css` enough, or is `tether-theme-basic.min.css` also needed?